# simple UV map on a cube gets rendering artifacts near edges

Tags: rendering, uv

I'm using 2.69. I have a simple cube object, and have set up UV mapping for the face and sides, and added an image as texture via this UV mapping.
The UV map is simple, just a cross, and I've welded the points together rather that having separate rectangles for the front face and each side.
All normals are facing outwards.
When rendering, I get artifacts near the edges, that show part of the hidden sides through the front face (bottom and right of the front face).
The cube is a simple cube, no subsurf or anything fancy.
What is wrong here ?
(the artifacts show here as black, if I disable shadows I see the hidden faces instead.)
[image]

Comment: OK, I could eventually solve this. Seems with a camera at 50mm focal length artifacts occur. Set focal to 100mm and moved camera, no more artifacts.

Comment: Make sure you answer your question down below

Comment: I just did above, what do you mean ? (not familiar with the site)

Comment: Just like people answer your question, you can answer your own. Scroll down on whatever device you are using, and choose answer question or something in between the lines of that. It's at the end of the comment section.

Comment: mh, whatever ? very non intuitive interface, sorry.

Comment: No problem! It's just good to increase reputation

Answer (score 1):

OK, I could eventually solve this. Seems with a camera at 50mm focal length artifacts occur. Set focal to 100mm and moved camera, no more artifacts.